# Minimum cost to visit the most cities, varying cost based on past cities

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I'm lost trying to figure out what algorithm can answer this question. Can this be done without bruteforcing all possible paths?

- There are 50 cities.
- For every city you visit, you pay for zero or more permits.
- Cities have a fixed list of permits they ask for. If you already paid for the same permits in a previously visited city then there's no need to pay for them again.
- You can pay for max N permits in your trip.

What's the route to visit the most cities without going over N paid permits?

Comment: List the cities in the order of the number of new permits.  Visit the cities in that order until you've reached N.

Comment: How many different permits are there?